# Find the position of subview in a View

Tags: iphone, ios, view, subviews

Goal : How we can find the position of subView in a View. I wants to find out the upper left (x,y)position of my scrollBar in a View, I am also using navigation Bar in my Application does it effect on the positioning of subViews from the Top?

I know how to find the height and width of subview like

```
CGSize viewSize = scrollView.frame.size;
height=viewSize.height;
width=viewSize.width;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're looking for is probably:

```
CGPoint viewPosition = scrollView.frame.origin;
x=viewPosition.x;
y=viewPosition.y;
```

But if you're looking to translate to another view's coordinate system, you could use:

```
- (CGPoint)convertPoint:(CGPoint)point toView:(UIView *)view
```

And pass it the point and view you wish to translate.

Answer (score 0):

To get the x and y use `origin`

```
CGPoint point = scrollView.frame.origin;
float x = point.x;
float y = point.y;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this one too...

```
 CGRect rect = [scrollBar frame];
 float origineFromX = rect.origin.x;
 float origineFromY = rect.origin.y;
```

may this will help you ...

Answer (score -1):

If you put navigation bar in the view, the position of the scrollview has to be shifted downwards to align properly in the view. The origin(top left position) of the scrollview will be different with and without the Navigation bar.

If you are using a fullscreen scrollview, you have to reduce the height of the scrollview to accomodate the navigation bar.